# How can I login to yarn non-interactively?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, continuous-integration, yarnpkg

When using `npm`, I can login non-interactively with:

```
$ printf "jesstelford\n<password>\nexample@email.com\n" | npm login
```

However, a similar command with `yarn` hangs:

```
$ printf "jesstelford\nexample@email.com\n" | yarn login
yarn login v0.21.3
question npm username: jesstelford
question npm email:
```

In interactive mode, I can successfully run:

```
$ yarn login
yarn login v0.21.3
question npm username: jesstelford
question npm email: example@email.com
✨  Done in 22.53s.
```

How can I run `yarn login` non-interactively?

Answer (score 6):

`yarn` appears to pause after the username is entered. You will also need to pause when in non-interactive mode:

```
$ { echo "jesstelford"; sleep 1; echo "example@email.com"; } | yarn login
```

This will give you the following output:

```
yarn login v0.21.3
question npm username: jesstelford
question npm email: example@email.com
✨  Done in 0.84s.
```

### How it works

`echo "jesstelford"` enters the string, followed by a newline character

`sleep 1` will insert a 1 second pause after entering the username, before continuing on to enter the email:

`echo "example@email.com"` enters the second string, followed by a newline character to end the command.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out how to make yarn use nexus credentials in Dockerfile.
If this can be done with nexus, I believe it will work for every other use case where it was problematic.

Here's the snippet:

```
# Install necessary package to login automatically
RUN npm install -g npm-cli-adduser

# Whenever auth changes, this has to be incremented,
# so following calls are not cached by Docker (or always build with --no-cache).
ARG FORCE_NO_CACHE_FLAG=2

# Authenticate to Nexus via npm package that does the job
RUN npm-cli-adduser -u ${NPM_USER} -p ${NPM_PASS} -e ${NPM_EMAIL} -r ${NPM_REGISTRY} -s ${NPM_SCOPE} -a

# Now, the fun / missing part I struggled with
# To fix yarn being silly aby not using token from npm-cli-adduser
# You need to set it explicitly.
# I found this by comparing my local `yarn config list` with a docker one.
# On local yarn was able to talk to nexus, not on docker. This piece one missing somehow.
RUN npm config set ${NPM_SCOPE}:registry ${NPM_REGISTRY}

# Now this will work, yarn will auth properly with your register.
RUN yarn install
```

This whole thing took me way too much. If there's anyone like me (or future me) with this problem, I hope this post will help.